# if var == False

Tags: python

In python you can write an if statement as follows

```
var = True
if var:
    print 'I\'m here'
```

is there any way to do the opposite without the ==, eg

```
var = False
if !var:
    print 'learnt stuff'
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use `not`

```
var = False
if not var:
    print 'learnt stuff'
```

Comment: How would you differentiate between False and None?

Comment: @AlxVallejo you made a good point here! That was worth an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978588/2648551 Thx for that suggestion.

Comment: lol was searching for it land on stakcoverflow , python is quite funny , i not understand why people love it so much.

Answer (score 71):

Since Python evaluates also the data type `NoneType` as `False` during the check, a more precise answer is:

```
var = False
if var is False:
    print('learnt stuff')
```

This prevents potentially unwanted behaviour such as:

```
var = []  # or None
if not var:
    print('learnt stuff') # is printed what may or may not be wanted
```

But if you want to check all cases where `var` will be evaluated to `False`, then doing it by using logical `not` keyword is the right thing to do.

Comment: I like this better because "explicit is better than implicit"

Answer (score 29):

Python uses `not` instead of `!` for negation.

Try

```
if not var: 
    print "learnt stuff"
```

instead

Answer (score 3):

```
var = False
if not var: print 'learnt stuff'
```

Comment: Why do all of these answers have the same example code, even though the original question didn't actually put the `if` and the `print` on the same line?

Comment: @Blender: The first revision of the question messed up the formatting so that each code snippet appeared on a single line.

Comment: @Blender: when I look at the revision history, I see the "original" (hard to tell inside the grace period) code as being a one-liner due to misformatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the 'not' operator?

```
if not var
```

Reference page:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm

Comment: That site has bad documentation.